# MS Access Form to add "And Or" operator in SQL Query

Tags: ms-access-2013

**Summary**: I've got a MS Access 2013 database containing information on employee transcripts, and currently configuring a form to let our educators create queries without needing to get technical in SQL or learn MS Access (i.e. text fields and drop downs). So far I have a few text box fields which work and allow them to search specific columns for information entered.

**What I'd like to do**: is add in a drop down that will add the "And" "Or" operator between fields. I'm having trouble figuring out the SQL syntax in the query to function.

**Here is the current code:** Training Title and Transcript Date are the two user input text boxes and Criteria 1 is the dropdown I have in the form to choose And Or

However, I'm getting syntax erros when I try to save it.

[MS Access Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqPFd.jpg)

````
WHERE (((User.[RN Residency]) =Forms!QBF_Form![RN Residency] Or Forms!QBF_Form![RN Residency] Is Null) 
AND 
(((Training.[Training Title]) Like "*"&Forms!QBF_Form![Training Title]& "*" Or Forms!QBF_Form![Training Title] Is Null) 
(Forms!QBF_Form![Criteria 1]) 
((Training.[Transcript Date]) Like "*"&Forms!QBF_Form![Transcript Date]&"*" Or Forms!QBF_Form![Transcript Date] Is Null))```
````

Answer (score 0):

First, you may have to specify the data type for the parameters.

Next, correct syntax

Finally, it could be:

```sql
PARAMETERS
    Forms!QBF_Form![RN Residency] Text,
    Forms!QBF_Form![Training Title] Text,
    Forms!QBF_Form![Transcript Date] DateTime;

<snip>

WHERE 
    ((User.[RN Residency] = Forms!QBF_Form![RN Residency] Or Forms!QBF_Form![RN Residency] Is Null) 
    AND 
    (Training.[Training Title] Like "*" & Forms!QBF_Form![Training Title] & "*" Or Forms!QBF_Form![Training Title] Is Null) 
    AND
    (Training.[Transcript Date] = Forms!QBF_Form![Transcript Date] Or Forms!QBF_Form![Transcript Date] Is Null))
```